# List some bands of a LANDSAT file using R

Tags: r, list, landsat

I have a folder with a LANDSAT image with 8 tif files.

```
list.files("C:/Users/Documents/04.HUMEDALES/L5__002072-09MAY-2006",  pattern = glob2rx("*.TIF"),full.names = TRUE)
```

As is shown:

```
[1] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B1.TIF" 
[2] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B2.TIF" 
[3] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B3.TIF" 
[4] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B4.TIF" 
[5] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B5.TIF" 
[6] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B6.TIF" 
[7] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_B7.TIF" 
[8] "C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006/LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_BQA.TIF"
```

How can I list only the tif files of the bands 1 to 5 and 7?
I can´t find the right pattern. This is the closest I get (which only remove the last file: BQA.tif)

```
list.files("C:/Users/Documents/04.HUMEDALES/L5__002072-09MAY-2006", pattern = glob2rx("*B?.TIF"), full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this set of files:

```
> list.files(".")
 [1] "bar-foo_B1.tif"  "bar-foo_B2.tif"  "bar-foo_B3.tif"  "bar-foo_B4.tif" 
 [5] "bar-foo_B5.tif"  "bar-foo_B6.tif"  "bar-foo_B7.tif"  "bar-foo_BQA.tif"
 [9] "foo_B1.tif"      "foo_B2.tif"      "foo_B3.tif"      "foo_B4.tif"     
[13] "foo_B5.tif"      "foo_B6.tif"      "foo_B7.tif"      "foo_BQA.tif"
```

I can select using this regex which matches anything (.*), B, 1 to 5 and 7, then ".tif" and then the end of the file name:

```
> list.files(".",pattern=".*B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=TRUE)
 [1] "bar-foo_B1.tif" "bar-foo_B2.tif" "bar-foo_B3.tif" "bar-foo_B4.tif"
 [5] "bar-foo_B5.tif" "bar-foo_B7.tif" "foo_B1.tif"     "foo_B2.tif"    
 [9] "foo_B3.tif"     "foo_B4.tif"     "foo_B5.tif"     "foo_B7.tif"
```

Comment: Upvoted, ... but I think the comma in the character class is not needed and possibly harmful, since commas were not a target match: `grepl( "[1-5,7]", c(",", 7))` #[1] TRUE TRUE and probably need to use `"\\.(tif|TIF)$"` and maybe even  add an extra |TIFF to be safe.

Comment: oops yes the comma is a mistake, and I've spelled out all the required digits instead since `[1-57]` could be misinterpreted as "1 to 57"!

Comment: I've also added `ignore.case=TRUE` to catch "tif" and "TIF", but that will hit lower-case "b1.tif" as well as "B1.tif".

Comment: Thank you! I solved with > list.files(".",pattern=".*B[123457]\\.tif$", ignore.case=TRUE)